# How do I count the longest consecutive '0' flanked by number '1' in is string using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do I count the longest consecutive  '0' flanked by number '1' in is string using pandas dataframe

Here's my dataset

```
Id     label
1          1
2         11
3        101
4      10101
5       1001
```

Here's my expected output

```
Id     label   result
1          1        0
2         11        0
3        101        1
4      10101        1
5       1001        2
```

Comment: On either side? So this would count as 2 zeros `10001`?

Comment: @yatu it count as 3

Comment: Okay... but the middle 0 is not flanked by a 1

Comment: @yatu why? I'm asking  longest consecutive `0` flanked by number `1`, `10001` is have 3 `0` that flanked by `1`

Comment: Okay gotcha @nabih

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try of using string related operations with split and count

Convert column to string -> followed by split with '1' and counting the max

```
df['result'] = df.label.astype(str).str.split('1').apply(lambda x: len(max(x)))
```

Out:

```
   Id      label  result
0   1   1         0
1   2   11        0
2   3   101       1
3   4   10101     1
4   5   1001      2
```

Comment: IIUC tis should be checking if there are 0s on both sides?

Comment: Yes @yatu, seems it could work in such conditions also len(max('0001011100'.split('1'))) :)

Answer (score 3):

After split get maximal value of length of lists and get length:

```
df['result'] = df['label'].astype(str).str.split('1').apply(lambda x: len(max(x, key=len)))
print (df)
   Id  label  result
0   1      1       0
1   2     11       0
2   3    101       1
3   4  10101       1
4   5   1001       2
```

Another solution:

```
df['result'] = df['label'].apply(lambda x: len(max(str(x).split('1'), key=str)))
```